# How to Download exe file using wget Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to download an exe file using wget.The below code doesn't work it stops like this

[image]

Popup about downloading an executable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import wget

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://youtube-dl.org/')
url = driver.find_element_by_link_text('youtube-dl.exe').click()
path = r'C:\Users\Helium\Desktop'
wget.download(url, path)
```

How to save the file .Am i doing wrong or Is there any possible way...

Comment: Are you gettnig this popup in wget or when doing `url = driver.find_element_by_link_text('youtube-dl.exe').click()`?

Comment: You don't have to bother with that popup window if you just download the exe from the official youtube-dl github page: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases

Comment: From this    "driver.find_element_by_link_text('youtube-dl.exe').click() "   @ tdelaney

Comment: i know the repo but i want to download from the webpages like these @jordanm

Comment: But not all websites are the same so your code will likely be non-resuable. If you know, for instance, that all downloads will be from GitHub, then you can search each site for GitHub urls, but, if not, unless you have a reliable way to find the download button in each page, it doesn't make sense to not download it from GitHub

Comment: I believe you can use chromedriver instead of Firefox and skip the pop-up, because chrome doesn't have one

Comment: Why do you click on the button though? Can't you just extract the download URL from the anchor without clicking it, then send the URL to wget?

Comment: Just trying the scenario without GitHub. Don't know how to  extract the download URL from the anchor without clicking it.@MarsNebulaSoup